# How to set by default selected value in angualr2 dropdown using ng-select?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have used angular2 drop-down for multiple value using follwing code:

```
 <ng-select [options]="dropDownSKUNumber" #SKUNumberDrp multiple="true" placeholder="Select SKU Number"  [allowClear]="true"></ng-select>
```

This code is working properly for me at the time of save multiple value.
Then but in view mode, I want that values by default in selected mode in dropdown, But i can't be able to do this.

How to solve it? using above code.

Comment: I assume you're using a third party directive for ng-select, could you specify which one you use? or did you write your own ng-select directive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using options, you must be using [this ng2-select](https://github.com/basvandenberg/angular2-select).
In this case, you should bind it to an `ngModel` and then update that value on init of your script:

I.e.
HTML

```
<ng-select
    [multiple]="true"
    [options]="myOptions"
    [(ngModel)]="mySelectValue">
</ng-select>
```

TS

```
export class App implements OnInit {

    myOptions: Array<any>;
    mySelectValue: Array<string>; // Array of strings for multi select, string for single select.

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myOptions = [
            {value: 'a', label: 'Alpha'},
            {value: 'b', label: 'Beta'},
            {value: 'c', label: 'Gamma'},
        ];
        this.mySelectValue = ['b', 'c'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [angular2 select](https://github.com/basvandenberg/angular2-select#use-with-ngmodel) you can use `ngModel` to set initial value :

you can use `options` as array and `ngModle` for selected value in your component as below  :

```
//Component 
public dropDownSKUNumber : any[] = [
  { value: 1, label : 1 },
  { value: 2, label : 2 },
  { value: 3, label : 3 }
];
public selectedValue: string[] = [ '2', '3' ];

//HTML
<ng-select [options]="dropDownSKUNumber" #SKUNumberDrp multiple="true" placeholder="Select SKU Number" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" [allowClear]="true"></ng-select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much your best support to me.

Comment: you can do `let selectedValue = "2, 3".split(",");` `split` will Split a string into an array of substrings check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: Above all sollitions are working for me but i am getting error like: 'Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined' and I am using ngmodel as mentioned in above code and also I have selectedValue in array but still ..??

Comment: I am getting my data in 'skuResponce.data' and i am using this code at component side  **this.model.Pack = skuResponse.data.Pack;                
                this.selectedValue = this.model.Pack.split(",");**

Comment: so i am getting my **selectedvalue** like  **["2" , "3" ]**